# React Native - Type Script: How to save dark mode toggle state even after turning off the application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, darkmode

What is the correct way so that I can save the dark mode switch even after turning off the application?
I want to use the use-state-persist library to achieve the goal.
In my example I show app.tsx , Preferences.tsx, ViewField.tsx .
So that it will be possible to understand how the logic is built

**DarkModeContext**

```
import React from 'react';

interface DarkMode {
  isDarkMode: boolean;
  setDarkMode: () => void;
}
export const DarkModeContext = React.createContext<DarkMode>({} as DarkMode);
```

**this is the app.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { syncStorage } from 'use-state-persist';

const App: () => ReactElement = () => {
  const [isDarkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  const initStorage = async () => await syncStorage.init();

const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!isDarkMode);
  };

  return (
    <DarkModeContext.Provider value={{ isDarkMode, toggleDarkMode }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerContent={SideMenu}
          screenOptions={{
            drawerPosition: 'right',
            headerShown: false,
            drawerType: 'front',
          }}
        >
          <Drawer.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={StackNavigator} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </DarkModeContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**this is the Preferences.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import ViewField from './ViewField';
import { DarkModeContext } from '~/context/DarkModeContext';
const Preferences = () => {
  const { isDarkMode, toggleDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

 return (
      <View>
 <ViewField title='dark mode' isEnabled={isDarkMode} setValue={toggleDarkMode} />
</View>
  );
};

export default Preferences;
```

**this is the ViewField.tsx**

```
import { View, Text, Switch } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ViewFieldStyles';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { DarkModeContext } from '~/context/DarkModeContext';

type Props = {
  title: string;
  isEnabled: boolean;
  setValue: () => void;
};
const ViewField = ({ title, isEnabled, setValue }: Props) => {
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

 return (
    <View style={isDarkMode ? styles.optionViewDark : styles.optionView}>
      <View style={styles.sameRowTextView}>
        <Text style={isDarkMode ? styles.optionTextDark : styles.optionText}>{title}</Text>
        <View style={styles.switchView}>
          <Switch
            trackColor={
              isDarkMode
                ? { false: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.38)', true: 'rgba(187, 134, 252, 0.38)' }
                : { false: '#767577', true: 'rgba(4, 76, 163, 0.38)' }
            }
onValueChange={setValue}
            value={isEnabled}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ViewField;
```

Comment: Why don't you save the preferences in your backend ? Maybe in your user table. When the user log, he can keep his preferences like dark theme cross devices

Comment: coz the goal is to implement it with use-state-persist library

Comment: Then you can just use `localStorage`

Comment: You can use Redux-Persist with Redux. so whenever the `toggleDarkMode` is called, you can update state variable, and it would be stored on AsycStorage automatically. and once the app is closed & reopened, the app restores this stored redux variable.

Comment: can u please show me how to do it in my code ?

Comment: @ 
Ilnur - i havnt redux in my app and also no the redux persist.
i have the use-state-persist ..and i want use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that there seems to be some problems in use-state-persist using [Boolean values](https://github.com/leoafarias/use-state-persist/issues/21). Furthermore, the latest published version of this library is from 2020.

However, the [use-state-persist](https://github.com/leoafarias/use-state-persist) library just seems to be a wrapper around [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage), which is very well maintained. I would encourage you to use this library instead.

In your case, this could be implemented as follows:

- Store the actual setter of the state in the context,
- Create an effect that accesses the async storage on mount of the application: if there exists a value for the corresponding key, set the state of the context, if not, then do nothing.
- In the `Preferences` component, store a new state in the async storage as well.

```js
const App: () => ReactElement = () => {
  const [isDarkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const contextValue = React.useMemo(() => ({
      isDarkMode,
      setDarkMode
  }), [isDarkMode])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isDarkMode');
        if (value !== null) {
            setDarkMode(JSON.parse(value));
        }
    }
    load();
  }, [])


  return (
    <DarkModeContext.Provider value={contextValue}>

   ...
};
```

In the `Preferences` component, set the state and save it to the local storage.

```js
const Preferences = () => {
   const { isDarkMode, setDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

   async function toggle() {
     const newValue = JSON.stringify(!isDarkMode);
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', newValue);
     setDarkMode(prev => !prev);
   }

   return (
      <View>
        <ViewField title='dark mode' isEnabled={isDarkMode} setValue={toggle} />
      </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: i think something wrong in Preferences..
it shuold be an async ?can u fix it ?

Comment: The `async` keyword should be enough.

Comment: how should be the iterface of the DarkModeContext ? 
i add my interface as it is now but the setDarkMode(prev => !prev); give an error type

Comment: It is correct how you did it, I have just noticed your edit.

Comment: something wrong..
in app.tsx the <DarkModeContext.Provider value={contextValue}> show me error :
"is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)"

Comment: Change the type of `setDarkMode` to `setDarkMode: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Boolean>>`